# SQL capitalize first and last letter of a name

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to make a query that is showing me last_name with first letter capitalized and also the last one capitalized.

Example: last_name='Alexander'
after query: last_name='AlexandeR'

I tried like this

```
select initcap(last_name)+LOWER(SUBSTR(last_name,2,LENGTH(last_name))) name_last from employees
```

but I am getting this error 01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"

I am using SQL Oracle DB

Can someone explain me what is the problem?

Comment: Use `||` for string concatenation in Oracle, not `+`.

Comment: `SELECT initcap(reverse(initcap(reverse(last_name))))` if you're feeling silly :-)

Comment: how I can capitalize the last letter?

Comment: @Jeroen - the outer initcap would override the changes made by the inner one, so you'd still end up with only the first letter capitalised. Nice try though *8-)

Comment: Ahhwww :( shame :D

Comment: That does expose a potential conundrum in the question: `initcap` does probably *not* do what PO thinks it does as it doesn't capitalize the first letter (but resets the entire string to Title Case).

Comment: Can u help me please
I have to do a query that is showing me when an employee is celebrating his hire_date

I have his hire_date in my table and I want to show when he will celebrate

Example:
employee=King
hire_date='03-01-1995'

after query:
King will celebrate on 03-01-2017

Comment: @AlexV - what does that have to do with this question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is the concatenation character.  However, I want to suggest a slightly different approach:

```
select (upper(substr(last_name, 1, 1)) ||
        substr(last_name, 2, len(last_name) - 2) ||
        upper(substr(last_name, -1, 1))
       )
```

In other words, avoid `initcap()`.  The issue is unexpected side-effects.  `initcap()` capitalizes the first letter of every word in the string.  So, if the name consisted of multiple words, then each would be capitalized.  Under such circumstances, I don't think it is wise to assume that the last name consists of only one name.

Comment: yes, it works fine, thank you, but instead of LEN in sql you have to use LENGTH

Comment: can u tell me, how I can write a float number, like commission, with zero padding to right
Example: commission_pct=0.5
after query, commission_pct=0.50000000
?

Comment: I found it
DECODE(commission_pct,NULL,'NO COMMISSION',TO_CHAR(rpad(COMMISSION_PCT,9,'0'))) comm

Answer (score 1):

To concatenate the string you are using '+' which is considering your string are number which is not the case and you are getting this error.

To concatenate strings in Oracle, please use either || operator or CONCAT() function.

So your query becomes like:

```
select initcap(last_name) || LOWER(SUBSTR(last_name,2,LENGTH(last_name))) name_last from employees;
```

Now you can modify this to get the output you are expecting.